# How to duplicate the field which is primarykey field?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a table with two primary key values(i.e; composite key),field names are id,date. So i want to save the same 'id' with different 'date' with in the next record also how can i overcome this?

Comment: What is your issue?  If the `id`/`date` combination is not in the table, then you are fine.

Comment: If i mentoined them as composite key then can i save any duplicate id in different record also?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use conflicting mythologies. Either use a primary auto incrementing key. Or use a composite key (name and date). If you are using a composite key usually the usefulness and purpose of a primary key is moot.

Comment: ok, then now consider 'name' in place of 'id' and can i give duplicate name in another record if name is pk?

Comment: If `name` is your pk, you cannot have two identical names in it. If `name,date` is your pk, you can have as many identical names as you want, as long as they differ in the date. (Assuming you have no other unique keys that may enforce additional restrictions).